# How to print 3 dice on one horizontal line in python

Tags: python, printing, output, line, dice

I have this code in python, the code prints each dice vertically by entering (r) instead of horizontally. Does anyone know how to edit this code to print 3 dice horizontally?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLzSy.jpg)

```
import random

x = "r"

while x == "r":
  no = random.randint(1,6)
  if no == 1: 
    print("[-----]") 
    print("[     ]") 
    print("[  0  ]") 
    print("[     ]") 
    print("[-----]")
  if no == 2: 
    print("[-----]") 
    print("[ 0   ]") 
    print("[     ]") 
    print("[   0 ]") 
    print("[-----]") 
  if no == 3: 
    print("[-----]") 
    print("[     ]") 
    print("[0 0 0]") 
    print("[     ]") 
    print("[-----]")
  if no == 4: 
    print("[-----]") 
    print("[0   0]") 
    print("[     ]") 
    print("[0   0]") 
    print("[-----]") 
  if no == 5: 
    print("[-----]") 
    print("[0   0]") 
    print("[  0  ]") 
    print("[0   0]") 
    print("[-----]") 
  if no == 6: 
    print("[-----]") 
    print("[0 0 0]") 
    print("[     ]") 
    print("[0 0 0]") 
    print("[-----]")  

  x=input("press r to roll again or e to exit:") 

  print("\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list to store the dice strings. Append to the string for each dice roll.

This will print the dice in a row for each roll:

```
import random

def drawdice(nums):
    rows = []  # all dice
    for no in nums:
      if no == 1: 
        rows.append(
        "[-----]" 
        "[     ]" 
        "[  0  ]" 
        "[     ]" 
        "[-----]")
      if no == 2: 
        rows.append(
        "[-----]" 
        "[ 0   ]" 
        "[     ]" 
        "[   0 ]" 
        "[-----]") 
      if no == 3: 
        rows.append(
        "[-----]" 
        "[     ]" 
        "[0 0 0]" 
        "[     ]" 
        "[-----]")
      if no == 4: 
        rows.append(
        "[-----]" 
        "[0   0]" 
        "[     ]" 
        "[0   0]" 
        "[-----]") 
      if no == 5: 
        rows.append(
        "[-----]" 
        "[0   0]" 
        "[  0  ]" 
        "[0   0]" 
        "[-----]") 
      if no == 6: 
        rows.append(
        "[-----]" 
        "[0 0 0]" 
        "[     ]" 
        "[0 0 0]" 
        "[-----]")  
      
    for rx in range(5):  # each row in dice
       for ry in rows:
          print(ry[rx*7:(rx+1)*7], end=' ')  # each dice
       print() # next row

print()
x = 'r'
while x != 'e':
  rolls = [random.randint(1,6) for n in range(3)]  # 3 dice
  drawdice(rolls)
  print("")  
  x=input("press enter to roll again or e to exit: ") 
  print("")
```

Output

```
[-----] [-----] [-----]
[     ] [0   0] [     ]
[  0  ] [  0  ] [0 0 0]
[     ] [0   0] [     ]
[-----] [-----] [-----]

press enter to roll again or e to exit:

[-----] [-----] [-----]
[     ] [ 0   ] [     ]
[0 0 0] [     ] [0 0 0]
[     ] [   0 ] [     ]
[-----] [-----] [-----]

press enter to roll again or e to exit:

[-----] [-----] [-----]
[0 0 0] [0   0] [0   0]
[     ] [     ] [     ]
[0 0 0] [0   0] [0   0]
[-----] [-----] [-----]
```

For completeness, you can also pack the dice strings in a list for display

```
def drawdice(nums):

    dice = [
    ["[-----]","[-----]","[-----]","[-----]","[-----]","[-----]"],
    ["[     ]","[ 0   ]","[     ]","[0   0]","[0   0]","[0 0 0]"],
    ["[  0  ]","[     ]","[0 0 0]","[     ]","[  0  ]","[     ]"],
    ["[     ]","[   0 ]","[     ]","[0   0]","[0   0]","[0 0 0]"],
    ["[-----]","[-----]","[-----]","[-----]","[-----]","[-----]"]
    ]
    
    for rx in dice:  # each row in dice
       for no in nums:
          print(rx[no-1], end=' ')
       print()
```

Output is the same

Comment: The dice count increases with each roll. Answer updated with full output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... now the output starts from 1 to ~ dice so how can I get 3 dice only on each row?

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what I wanted .... you are genius

Comment: Hey Mike can you help me with the Python script? I have the code but I want to write it in a different way if it possible.